# How to make Google Docs presentation in a Google Sites web page publicly viewable?

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites, google-slides

I embedded a presentation in a web page all inside the same Google Apps domain but only people who are signed in can see the presentation.

I am the domain admin and I modified the setting in *Manage this domain -> Settings -> Docs -> Sharing* to **"Users can share documents outside this organization"** but still when I publish the presentation using *Publish/Embed* it says **"This document is published only within *My Domain*."**.

How can I make it viewable to outsiders not only domain members?

Comment: Could you post the link to your presentation/site?

Comment: Looks that it's obsolete. Are you still having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Site Permissions on the Google Site where you embedded the presentation. Is it set so anyone on the Internet can view it?

Comment: Yes the site is viewable to public. It also contains some spreadsheet forms that are available to public and they work fine. Only the presentation displays error saying you must login.

Comment: @M.Sameer: You have to make your presentation public.

Comment: @Robert : The presentation is public. There is an issue at Google that prevents presentations and gadgets from appearing in mapped URLs in Google Apps. It's not solved yet.