# Can't see "Tasks" in list of calendars

Tags: google-calendar

When I look to 'My Calendars' on the left side, while I see other calendars but not the "Task" calendar.  I went into settings and there is no "task" calendar to select.  I am obviously missing something fundamental but I have spent much time looking without figuring it out.

Comment: Possibly Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/how-to-make-google-docs-presentation-in-a-google-sites-web-page-publicly-viewabl

Comment: Is it listed in the [settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#settings-calendars_9)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the "Reminders" calendar? If so then you can click the dropdown options for this and "Switch to Tasks". You can toggle between "Reminders" and "Tasks", but you don't seem to be able to display both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration.  No, the problem is precisely that there is no "reminders" calendar. ?

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say you "see other calendars", you don't literally mean you see the "Other calendars" section immediately below the "My calendars" heading? Presumably the "My calendars" section is expanded and you see a list of your existing calendars _before_ the "Other calendars" section?